# Limit number of terms that a custom taxonomy can save per custom post type

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, terms

I want to limit custom taxonomy created per post to be limited to 1. So, only 1 tag, or 1 category added to a custom post type.

I looked into `wp_set_object_terms` and unfortunately, action/filters are a bit too late there to do anything about this.

Any ideas? Where can I hook myself to unset the rest of the term array and leave just 1?

Comment: I stumbled here looking something else. But I've actually written a plugin that will do this for you: [Radio Buttons for Taxonomies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/radio-buttons-for-taxonomies/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Taxonomy Single Term](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Taxonomy_Single_Term) is a small library that helps to implemement this functionality.

## Usage

1. Include the `class.taxonomy-single-term.php` file from within your plugin or theme
2. Initialize the class (update the taxonomy slug with your own): `$custom_tax_mb = new Taxonomy_Single_Term( 'custom-tax-slug' );`

### Optional

1. The second parameter is an array of post_types and the third parameter is either 'radio', or 'select' (defaulting to radio). To use a `select` type on the `foo` post_type:  `$custom_tax_mb = new Taxonomy_Single_Term( 'custom-tax-slug', array( 'foo' ), 'select' );`
2. Update optional class properties like this:

```
// Priority of the metabox placement.
$custom_tax_mb->set( 'priority', 'low' );

// 'normal' to move it under the post content.
$custom_tax_mb->set( 'context', 'normal' );

// Custom title for your metabox
$custom_tax_mb->set( 'metabox_title', __( 'Custom Metabox Title', 'your-text-domain' ) );

// Makes a selection required.
$custom_tax_mb->set( 'force_selection', true );

// Will keep radio elements from indenting for child-terms.
$custom_tax_mb->set( 'indented', false );

// Allows adding of new terms from the metabox
$custom_tax_mb->set( 'allow_new_terms', true );
```

For completeness, here is the main include, `class.taxonomy-single-term.php`:

```
<?php

if ( ! class_exists( 'Taxonomy_Single_Term' ) ) :
/**
 * Removes and replaces the built-in taxonomy metabox with <select> or series of <input type="radio" />
 *
 * Usage:
 *
 * $custom_tax_mb = new Taxonomy_Single_Term( 'custom-tax-slug', array( 'post_type' ), 'type' ); // 'type' can be 'radio' or 'select' (default: radio)
 *
 * Update optional properties:
 *
 * $custom_tax_mb->set( 'priority', 'low' );
 * $custom_tax_mb->set( 'context', 'normal' );
 * $custom_tax_mb->set( 'metabox_title', __( 'Custom Metabox Title', 'yourtheme' ) );
 * $custom_tax_mb->set( 'force_selection', true );
 * $custom_tax_mb->set( 'indented', false );
 * $custom_tax_mb->set( 'allow_new_terms', true );
 *
 * @link  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Parameters
 * @link  https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Taxonomy_Single_Term/blob/master/README.md
 * @version  0.2.1
 */
class Taxonomy_Single_Term {

    /**
     * Post types where metabox should be replaced (defaults to all post_types associated with taxonomy)
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @var array
     */
    protected $post_types = array();

    /**
     * Taxonomy slug
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @var string
     */
    protected $slug = '';

    /**
     * Taxonomy object
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @var object
     */
    protected $taxonomy = false;

    /**
     * Taxonomy_Single_Term_Walker object
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @var object
     */
    protected $walker = false;

    /**
     * New metabox title. Defaults to Taxonomy name
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @var string
     */
    protected $metabox_title = '';

    /**
     * Metabox priority. (vertical placement)
     * 'high', 'core', 'default' or 'low'
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @var string
     */
    protected $priority = 'high';

    /**
     * Metabox position. (column placement)
     * 'normal', 'advanced', or 'side'
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @var string
     */
    protected $context = 'side';

    /**
     * Set to true to hide "None" option & force a term selection
     * @since 0.1.1
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $force_selection = false;

    /**
     * Whether hierarchical taxonomy inputs should be indented to represent hierarchy
     * @since 0.1.2
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $indented = true;

    /**
     * Checks if there is a bulk-edit term to set
     * @var boolean|term object
     */
    protected $to_set = false;

    /**
     * Array of post ids whose terms have been reset from bulk-edit. (prevents recursion)
     * @var array
     */
    protected $single_term_set = array();

    /**
     * What input element to use in the taxonomy meta box (radio or select)
     * @var array
     */
    protected $input_element = 'radio';

    /**
     * Whether adding new terms via the metabox is permitted
     * @since 0.2.0
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $allow_new_terms = false;

    /**
     * Initiates our metabox action
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @param string $tax_slug      Taxonomy slug
     * @param array  $post_types    post-types to display custom metabox
     */
    public function __construct( $tax_slug, $post_types = array(), $type = 'radio' ) {

        $this->slug = $tax_slug;
        $this->post_types = is_array( $post_types ) ? $post_types : array( $post_types );
        $this->input_element = in_array( (string) $type, array( 'radio', 'select' ) ) ? $type : $this->input_element;

        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_input_element' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_footer', array( $this, 'js_checkbox_transform' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_taxonomy_single_term_add', array( $this, 'ajax_add_term' ) );

        // Handle bulk-editing
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['bulk_edit'] ) && 'Update' == $_REQUEST['bulk_edit'] ) {
            $this->bulk_edit_handler();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes and replaces the built-in taxonomy metabox with our own.
     * @since 0.1.0
     */
    public function add_input_element() {

        // test the taxonomy slug construtor is an actual taxonomy
        if ( ! $this->taxonomy() ) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ( $this->post_types() as $key => $cpt ) {
            // remove default category type metabox
            remove_meta_box( $this->slug . 'div', $cpt, 'side' );
            // remove default tag type metabox
            remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-' . $this->slug, $cpt, 'side' );
            // add our custom radio box
            add_meta_box( $this->slug . '_input_element', $this->metabox_title(), array( $this, 'input_element' ), $cpt, $this->context, $this->priority );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays our taxonomy input metabox
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @todo Abstract inline javascript to it's own file and localize it
     */
    public function input_element() {

        // uses same noncename as default box so no save_post hook needed
        wp_nonce_field( 'taxonomy_'. $this->slug, 'taxonomy_noncename' );

        $class       = $this->indented ? 'taxonomydiv' : 'not-indented';
        $class      .= 'category' !== $this->slug ? ' ' . $this->slug . 'div' : '';
        $class      .= ' tabs-panel';

        $this->namefield    = 'category' == $this->slug ? 'post_category' : 'tax_input[' . $this->slug . ']';
        $this->namefield    = $this->taxonomy()->hierarchical ? $this->namefield . '[]' : $this->namefield;

        $el_open_cb  = $this->input_element . '_open';
        $el_close_cb = $this->input_element . '_close';

        ?>
        <div id="taxonomy-<?php echo $this->slug; ?>" class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
            <?php $this->{$el_open_cb}() ?>
            <?php $this->term_fields_list(); ?>
            <?php $this->{$el_close_cb}() ?>
            <?php if ( $this->allow_new_terms ) {
                $this->terms_adder_button();
            } ?>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Select wrapper open
     * @since  0.2.0
     */
    public function select_open() {
        ?>
        <select style="display:block;width:100%;margin-top:12px;" name="<?php echo $this->namefield; ?>" id="<?php echo $this->slug; ?>checklist" class="form-no-clear">
            <?php if ( ! $this->force_selection ) : ?>
                <option value="0"><?php echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'taxonomy_single_term_select_none', __( 'None' ) ) ); ?></option>
            <?php endif;
    }

    /**
     * Radio wrapper open
     * @since  0.2.0
     */
    public function radio_open() {
        ?>
        <ul id="<?php echo $this->slug; ?>checklist" data-wp-lists="list:<?php echo $this->slug; ?>" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">
            <?php if ( ! $this->force_selection ) : ?>
                <li style="display:none;">
                    <input id="taxonomy-<?php echo $this->slug; ?>-clear" type="radio" name="<?php echo $this->namefield; ?>" value="0" />
                </li>
            <?php endif;
    }

    /**
     * Select wrapper close
     * @since  0.2.0
     */
    public function select_close() {
        ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Radio wrapper close
     * @since  0.2.0
     */
    public function radio_close() {
        ?>
        </ul>
        <p style="margin-bottom:0;float:left;width:50%;">
            <a class="button" id="taxonomy-<?php echo $this->slug; ?>-trigger-clear" href="#"><?php _e( 'Clear' ); ?></a>
        </p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('#taxonomy-<?php echo $this->slug; ?>-trigger-clear').click(function(){
                    $('#taxonomy-<?php echo $this->slug; ?> input:checked').prop( 'checked', false );
                    $('#taxonomy-<?php echo $this->slug; ?>-clear').prop( 'checked', true );
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * wp_terms_checklist wrapper which outputs the terms list
     * @since  0.2.0
     */
    public function term_fields_list() {
        wp_terms_checklist( get_the_ID(), array(
            'taxonomy'      => $this->slug,
            'selected_cats' => false,
            'popular_cats'  => false,
            'checked_ontop' => false,
            'walker'        => $this->walker(),
        ) );
    }

    /**
     * Adds button (and associated JS) for adding new terms
     * @since 0.2.0
     */
    public function terms_adder_button() {
        ?>
        <p style="margin-bottom:0;float:right;width:50%;text-align:right;">
            <a class="button-secondary" id="taxonomy-<?php echo $this->slug; ?>-new" href="#"<?php if ( 'radio' == $this->input_element ) : ?> style="display:inline-block;margin-top:0.4em;"<?php endif; ?>><?php _e( 'Add New' ); ?></a>
        </p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('#taxonomy-<?php echo $this->slug; ?>-new').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var termName = prompt( "Add New <?php echo esc_attr( $this->taxonomy()->labels->singular_name ); ?>", "New <?php echo esc_attr( $this->taxonomy()->labels->singular_name ); ?>" );

                    if( ! termName ) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if(termName != null) {
                        var data = {
                            'action'    : 'taxonomy_single_term_add',
                            'term_name' : termName,
                            'taxonomy'  : '<?php echo $this->slug; ?>',
                            'nonce'     : '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'taxonomy_'. $this->slug, '_add_term' ); ?>'
                        };
                        $.post( ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                            window.console.log( 'response', response );
                            if( response.success ){
                                <?php if ( 'radio' == $this->input_element ) : ?>
                                    $('#taxonomy-<?php echo $this->slug; ?> input:checked').prop( 'checked', false );
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    $('#taxonomy-<?php echo $this->slug; ?> option').prop( 'selected', false );
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                $('#<?php echo $this->slug; ?>checklist').append( response.data );
                            } else {
                                window.alert( '<?php printf( __( 'There was a problem adding a new %s' ), esc_attr( $this->taxonomy()->labels->singular_name ) ); ?>: ' + "\n" + response.data );
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * AJAX callback to add terms inline
     * @since 0.2.0
     */
    function ajax_add_term() {
        $nonce     = isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['nonce'] ) : '';
        $term_name = isset( $_POST['term_name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['term_name'] ) : false;
        $taxonomy  = isset( $_POST['taxonomy'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['taxonomy'] ) : false;

        $friendly_taxonomy = $this->taxonomy()->labels->singular_name;

        // Ensure user is allowed to add new terms
        if( !$this->allow_new_terms ) {
            wp_send_json_error( __( "New $friendly_taxonomy terms are not allowed" ) );
        }

        if( !taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ) {
            wp_send_json_error( __( "Taxonomy $friendly_taxonomy does not exist. Cannot add term" ) );
        }

        if( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'taxonomy_' . $taxonomy, '_add_term' ) ) {
            wp_send_json_error( __( "Cheatin' Huh? Could not verify security token" ) );
        }

        if( term_exists( $term_name, $taxonomy ) ) {
            wp_send_json_error( __( "The term '$term_name' already exists in $friendly_taxonomy" ) );
        }

        $result = wp_insert_term( $term_name, $taxonomy );

        if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
            wp_send_json_error( $result->get_error_message() );
        }

        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $result['term_id'], $taxonomy );

        if ( ! isset( $term->term_id ) ) {
            wp_send_json_error();
        }


        $field_name = $taxonomy == 'category'
            ? 'post_category'
            : 'tax_input[' . $taxonomy . ']';

        $field_name = $this->taxonomy()->hierarchical
            ? $field_name . '[]'
            : $field_name;

        $args = array(
            'id'            => $taxonomy . '-' . $term->term_id,
            'name'          => $field_name,
            'value'         => $this->taxonomy()->hierarchical ? $term->term_id : $term->slug,
            'checked'       => ' checked="checked"',
            'selected'      => ' selected="selected"',
            'disabled'      => '',
            'label'         => esc_html( apply_filters( 'the_category', $term->name ) ),
        );

        $output = '';
        $output .= 'radio' == $this->input_element
            ? $this->walker()->start_el_radio( $args )
            : $this->walker()->start_el_select( $args );

        // $output is handled by reference
        $this->walker()->end_el( $output, $term );

        wp_send_json_success( $output );

    }

    /**
     * Add some JS to the post listing page to transform the quickedit inputs
     * @since  0.1.3
     */
    public function js_checkbox_transform() {
        $screen = get_current_screen();
        $taxonomy = $this->taxonomy();

        if (
            empty( $taxonomy ) || empty( $screen )
            || ! isset( $taxonomy->object_type )
            || ! isset( $screen->post_type )
            || ! in_array( $screen->post_type, $taxonomy->object_type )
        )
            return;

        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Handles changing input types to radios for WDS_Taxonomy_Radio
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                var $postsFilter = $('#posts-filter');
                var $theList = $postsFilter.find('#the-list');

                // Handles changing the input type attributes
                var changeToRadio = function( $context ) {
                    $context = $context ? $context : $theList;
                    var $taxListInputs = $context.find( '.<?php echo $this->slug; ?>-checklist li input' );
                    if ( $taxListInputs.length ) {
                        // loop and switch input types
                        $taxListInputs.each( function() {
                            $(this).attr( 'type', 'radio' ).addClass('transformed-to-radio');
                        });
                    }
                };

                $postsFilter
                    // Handle converting radios in bulk-edit row
                    .on( 'click', '#doaction, #doaction2', function(){
                        var name = $(this).attr('id').substr(2);
                        if ( 'edit' === $( 'select[name="' + name + '"]' ).val() ) {
                            setTimeout( function() {
                                changeToRadio( $theList.find('#bulk-edit') );
                            }, 50 );
                        }
                    })
                    // when clicking new radio inputs, be sure to uncheck all but the one clicked
                    .on( 'change', '.transformed-to-radio', function() {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        $siblings = $this.parents( '.<?php echo $this->slug; ?>-checklist' ).find( 'li .transformed-to-radio' ).prop( 'checked', false );
                        $this.prop( 'checked', true );
                    });

                // Handle converting radios in inline-edit rows
                $theList.find('.editinline').on( 'click', function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    setTimeout( function() {
                        var $editRow = $this.parents( 'tr' ).next().next();
                        changeToRadio( $editRow );
                    }, 50 );
                });

            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Handles checking if object terms need to be set when bulk-editing posts
     * @since  0.2.1
     */
    public function bulk_edit_handler() {
        // Get wp tax name designation
        $name = $this->slug;

        if ( 'category' == $name ) {
            $name = 'post_category';
        }

        if ( 'tag' == $name ) {
            $name = 'post_tag';
        }

        // If this tax name exists in the query arg
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ $name ] ) && is_array( $_REQUEST[ $name ] ) ) {
            $this->to_set = end( $_REQUEST[ $name ] );
        } elseif ( isset( $_REQUEST['tax_input'][ $name ] ) && is_array( $_REQUEST['tax_input'][ $name ] ) ) {
            $this->to_set = end( $_REQUEST['tax_input'][ $name ] );
        }

        // Then get it's term object
        if ( $this->to_set ) {
            $this->to_set = get_term( $this->to_set, $this->slug );
            // And hook in our re-save action
            add_action( 'set_object_terms', array( $this, 'maybe_resave_terms' ), 10, 5 );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles resaving terms to post when bulk-editing so that only one term will be applied
     * @since  0.1.4
     * @param  int    $object_id  Object ID.
     * @param  array  $terms      An array of object terms.
     * @param  array  $tt_ids     An array of term taxonomy IDs.
     * @param  string $taxonomy   Taxonomy slug.
     * @param  bool   $append     Whether to append new terms to the old terms.
     * @param  array  $old_tt_ids Old array of term taxonomy IDs.
     */
    public function maybe_resave_terms( $object_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $taxonomy, $append ) {
        if (
            // if the terms being edited are not this taxonomy
            $taxonomy != $this->slug
            // or we already did our magic
            || in_array( $object_id, $this->single_term_set, true )
        ) {
            // Then bail
            return;
        }

        // Prevent recursion
        $this->single_term_set[] = $object_id;
        // Replace terms with the one term
        wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, $this->to_set->slug, $taxonomy, $append );
    }

    /**
     * Gets the taxonomy object from the slug
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @return object Taxonomy object
     */
    public function taxonomy() {
        $this->taxonomy = $this->taxonomy ? $this->taxonomy : get_taxonomy( $this->slug );
        return $this->taxonomy;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the taxonomy's associated post_types
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @return array Taxonomy's associated post_types
     */
    public function post_types() {
        $this->post_types = !empty( $this->post_types ) ? $this->post_types : $this->taxonomy()->object_type;
        return $this->post_types;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the metabox title from the taxonomy object's labels (or uses the passed in title)
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @return string Metabox title
     */
    public function metabox_title() {
        $this->metabox_title = !empty( $this->metabox_title ) ? $this->metabox_title : $this->taxonomy()->labels->name;
        return $this->metabox_title;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the Taxonomy_Single_Term_Walker object for use in term_fields_list and ajax_add_term
     * @since 0.2.0
     * @return object Taxonomy_Single_Term_Walker object
     */
    public function walker() {
        if ( $this->walker ) {
            return $this->walker;
        }
        require_once( 'walker.taxonomy-single-term.php' );
        $this->walker = new Taxonomy_Single_Term_Walker( $this->taxonomy()->hierarchical, $this->input_element );

        return $this->walker;
    }

    /**
     * Set the object properties.
     *
     * @since 0.2.1
     *
     * @param string $property  Property in object.  Must be set in object.
     * @param mixed  $value     Value of property.
     *
     * @return Taxonomy_Single_Term  Returns Taxonomy_Single_Term object, allows for chaining.
     */
    public function set( $property, $value ) {

        if ( property_exists( $this, $property ) ) {
            $this->$property = $value;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Magic getter for our object.
     *
     * @since  0.2.1
     *
     * @param  string    Property in object to retrieve.
     * @throws Exception Throws an exception if the field is invalid.
     *
     * @return mixed     Property requested.
     */
    public function __get( $property ) {
        if ( property_exists( $this, $value ) ) {
            return $this->{$property};
        } else {
            throw new Exception( 'Invalid '. __CLASS__ .' property: ' . $field );
        }
    }

}

endif; // class_exists check
```

The library also uses a custom walker, `walker.taxonomy-single-term.php`:

```
<?php

if ( ! class_exists( 'Taxonomy_Single_Term_Walker' ) && class_exists( 'Walker' ) ) :

/**
 * Walker to output an unordered list of taxonomy radio <input> elements.
 *
 * @see Walker
 * @see wp_category_checklist()
 * @see wp_terms_checklist()
 * @since 0.1.2
 */
class Taxonomy_Single_Term_Walker extends Walker {
    public $tree_type = 'category';
    public $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'term_id' ); //TODO: decouple this

    public function __construct( $hierarchical, $input_element ) {
        $this->hierarchical = $hierarchical;
        $this->input_element = $input_element;
    }

    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @see Walker:start_lvl()
     *
     * @since 0.1.2
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of category. Used for tab indentation.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_terms_checklist()
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( 'radio' == $this->input_element ) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "$indent<ul class='children'>\n";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
     *
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     *
     * @since 0.1.2
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of category. Used for tab indentation.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_terms_checklist()
     */
    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( 'radio' == $this->input_element ) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     *
     * @since 0.1.2
     *
     * @param string $output   Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $term The current term object.
     * @param int    $depth    Depth of the term in reference to parents. Default 0.
     * @param array  $args     An array of arguments. @see wp_terms_checklist()
     * @param int    $id       ID of the current term.
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $term, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

        $taxonomy = empty( $args['taxonomy'] ) ? 'category' : $args['taxonomy'];
        $name = $taxonomy == 'category' ? 'post_category' : 'tax_input['.$taxonomy.']';
        // input name
        $name = $this->hierarchical ? $name .'[]' : $name;
        // input value
        $value = $this->hierarchical ? $term->term_id : $term->slug;

        $selected_cats = empty( $args['selected_cats'] ) ? array() : $args['selected_cats'];
        $in_selected   = in_array( $term->term_id, $selected_cats );

        $args = array(
            'id'            => $taxonomy .'-'. $term->term_id,
            'name'          => $name,
            'value'         => $value,
            'checked'       => checked( $in_selected, true, false ),
            'selected'      => selected( $in_selected, true, false ),
            'disabled'      => disabled( empty( $args['disabled'] ), false, false ),
            'label'         => esc_html( apply_filters('the_category', $term->name ) )
        );

        $output .= 'radio' == $this->input_element
            ? $this->start_el_radio( $args )
            : $this->start_el_select( $args );
    }

    /**
     * Creates the opening markup for the radio input
     *
     * @since  0.2.0
     *
     * @param  array  $args Array of arguments for creating the element
     *
     * @return string       Opening li element and radio input
     */
    public function start_el_radio( $args ) {
        return "\n".sprintf(
            '<li id="%s"><label class="selectit"><input value="%s" type="radio" name="%s" id="in-%s" %s %s/>%s</label>',
            $args['id'],
            $args['value'],
            $args['name'],
            $args['id'],
            $args['checked'],
            $args['disabled'],
            $args['label']
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates the opening markup for the select input
     *
     * @since  0.2.0
     *
     * @param  array  $args Array of arguments for creating the element
     *
     * @return string       Opening option element and option text
     */
    public function start_el_select( $args ) {
        return "\n".sprintf(
            '<option %s %s id="%s" value="%s" class="class-single-term">%s',
            $args['selected'],
            $args['disabled'],
            $args['id'],
            $args['value'],
            $args['label']
        );
    }

    /**
     * Ends the element output, if needed.
     *
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     *
     * @since 0.1.2
     *
     * @param string $output   Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $term The current term object.
     * @param int    $depth    Depth of the term in reference to parents. Default 0.
     * @param array  $args     An array of arguments. @see wp_terms_checklist()
     */
    public function end_el( &$output, $term, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( 'radio' == $this->input_element ) {
            $output .= "</li>\n";
        } else {
            $output .= "</option>\n";
        }
    }

}

endif; // class_exists check
```

### Fix for Quick Edit

At the time of this writing (WordPress v4.6.1), there is an issue with setting single terms on the Quick Edit screen. [Here's the fix](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Taxonomy_Single_Term/issues/16), which has not yet been merged yet:

Change line: 438 in class.taxonomy.single-term.php to:

```
var $editRow = $this.parents( 'tr' ).next().next();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! this class deals with front-end right? and doesn't change how things are handled in backend? e.g. still multiple terms can be saved but not via meta boxes.

Comment: Hello, happy to help! This library swaps out the meta boxes on the post edit screens for the taxonomy/post type specified in the configuration. The taxonomy edit pages in the admin are unaffected. So, you can create as many terms as you need, but posts will only be able to be associated with one term. This plugin does not deal with the front end of the site.